# How to change CSS "position" on div when it reaches the end of container div?

Tags: javascript, css, position

I'm working on a feature for a website that creates a bar on the left side of a single post page that contains social share buttons. The bar follows the reader down the page as they scroll. It's similar to the one found on Mashable.com.

However, the bar will keep scrolling down the page into the footer area of the site, but I'd like for it to stop when it reaches the end of the container div (the main page content between header and footer).

I'm guessing JavaScript is involved that works on changing the "position:fixed" to "position:absolute" but I'm not sure what the exact code is.

Does anyone have thoughts/can help me out?

Comment: if you don't get the answer i will post tomorrow, i did that two days a go! [....] 

But what you basically need to do is to toggle the position property to static (when the paged is loaded or when the scrollTop is lower than the desired), fixed (when it reaches to the desired scrollTop position; for example, top:15px;) a and fixed (top:15px - $('#end').offset().top + $('#fixed_element).height() when you want to simulate that the fixed bar is not following to the scoll anymore). happy coding

Comment: Do you want it inside the container div?

Comment: Yes, I'd like it inside the container div. I'm not that good with JavaScript, so anything less than basic would have to be written out for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Like this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NAtKk/embedded/result/)** ?

The basic jQuery is:

```
var stickerTop = parseInt($('#sticker').offset().top);
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $("#sticker").css((parseInt($(window).scrollTop()) + parseInt($("#sticker").css('margin-top')) > stickerTop) ? {
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '0px'
    } : {
        position: 'relative'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery plugin does this properly in staying within its container while keeping at the top when possible : https://github.com/sebringj/jquery.dumbfixed

```
 $('#middle .right').dumbFixed();
```

The selected item does some minor modifications to its parent such as setting min-width and min-height to its own dimensions because parent may have no dimensions set and will rely on its child to push it to its own dimensions.